# ImportError while using cPickle with Flask

Tags: python, pickle

After creating an object instance for a python class like:

```
inst = ClassName(var1, var2)
```

NOTE: I need the pickle dump because creation of instance is a one-time task and takes a long time.

I did the cPickle dump like:

```
with open("filename.pickle", "w") as output_file:
    cPickle.dump(inst, output_file)
```

Now when I execute this as a normal python program (with the cPickle.load in a file and using the 'python' command), it works perfectly:

```
with open("filename.pickle", "r") as input_file:
    final_inst = cPickle.load(input_file)
```

But, when I write the SAME code in a Flask route, I get:

> ImportError: No module named ClassName

I need the `final_inst` to proceed further

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Ivam

Comment: This is purely an import issue. The module that contains class name isn’t getting imported because python didn’t know how to find it.It’s likely that the flask app is running in a venv which is pointing at a different site-packages directory or something like that. Easy trouble shooting steps would be to compare your sys.path list in the working module against your non working one: import sys.path print(sys.path), also you can run this in each one to see where it physically located on the drive: print(module_class_name_is_imported_from.__file__)

Comment: @csevier Right on! It was an import error. First I got the absolute path for the ClassName using :
import os
import ClassName
os.path.abspath(ClassName.__file__)

After that, I added the following code just before load : 
import sys
sys.path.append('path/to/ClassName')

Thank you very much. Stuck on this for the entire day.

Comment: cool! Although that defiantly works I’d advise against manipulating sys.path manually like that. Instead make virtual environments that house your dependencies per project and pip install to those isolated interpreters :)

Comment: moved my comment to an answer if you don’t mind selecting it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is purely an import issue. The module that contains class name isn’t getting imported because python didn’t know how to find it.It’s likely that the flask app is running in a venv which is pointing at a different site-packages directory or something like that. Easy trouble shooting steps would be to compare your sys.path list in the working module against your non working one: import sys.path print(sys.path), also you can run this in each one to see where it physically located on the drive: print(module_class_name_is_imported_from.**file**)

Answer (score 0):

It's slightly difficult to tell from the snippet but the pickle will rely upon the loaded modules within the globals. The class should be imported into the global scope before you unpickle your data back into the class `ClassName`.

Ensure the `ClassName` is imported into the same space as your load function. In flask - the same file is fine. You should import the class is absolutely.

```
from other import ClassName

def some_function():
    with open("filename.pickle", "r") as input_file:
        final_inst = cPickle.load(input_file)
    return FlaskResponse('Thing')
```

Answer (score 0):

@csevier Right on! It was an import error. Thank you!
First I got the absolute path in the python console for the ClassName using :
        import os 
        import ClassName
        os.path.abspath(ClassName.**file**)

After that, I added the following code just before load : 
        import sys 
        sys.path.append('path/to/ClassName')